# C# XMLReader acts up after attempting to read a too big element

Tags: c#, error-handling, large-data, large-files, xmlreader

I have a very simple XML, but where one child element is a DNA string. This string can be anything from a few hundred characters long to 3 billion (like in the human genome). Of course reading a record where such an element is included will cause an Out of Memory Exception.

Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ROOT>
      <RECORD>
        <ID>OX451740</ID>
          <DNASEQ>
          tctacttcactcacgtaagtgatacc.... 1.2 BILLION MORE!!!!.... tctacttcactcacgtaagtgatacc
          </DNASEQ>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
        <ID>OU641503</ID>
        <DNASEQ>
        gtaaccaaatcggtgctgctttctggtacgtgttgcagaccctgaaccatcaattgttgga
        </DNASEQ>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
        <ID>Y19466</ID>
         <DNASEQ>
         atcgtcacccccccgcccgccacacctgacaaacaagatgtgcggcgggggtggaa
         </DNASEQ>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
        <ID>AM472099</ID>
        <DNASEQ>
        cagttgacactctccttctcataaaattttgtaagcacaaccacatcacaactat
        </DNASEQ>
      </RECORD>
    </ROOT>
```

Thing is, catching the exception and then continuing parsing will cause more errors, even when the rest of the records in the XML have no long DNA strings.

If I delete the record in question, the all records in the file are read just fine.

Of course the file itself can be up to gigabytes in size - therefore I use the XMLReader to not load the whole file into memory.

Happy to share the real XML file if that can help.

So my code is as follows:

```
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Xml;
    namespace LargeXMLReader
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
                settings.CheckCharacters = true;
                settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml", settings))
                {
                    reader.ReadStartElement("ROOT");
                    while (!reader.EOF)
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "RECORD")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                XElement el = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
                                foreach (XElement e in el.Elements())
                                {
                                    if(e.Name == "ID")
                                        Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Too big element...");
                                reader.Read();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would expect it to fail on the first record, but it also fails on the last one. If I delete the large record from the XML, it will read all just fine. For my real data XML it will now fail on the large one, and then fail over and over going through the rest or the records, but not all... Very strange.

Bug in XMLReader? Can Base64 help somehow?

Comment: Here is the file in question
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t12s9p39x65u4o1/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Would it be possible to read the DNASEQ in chunks of say 100M characters and use the element contents as a array of strings instead of single string? What would that look like with XMLReader, or should I just code my own basic reader that really reads every element one by one / line by line?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with such a large element? How would you store it in memory? If you just want to ignore it, it might be worth just using a custom `Stream` wrapper that would search for the next `<>` closing tag, and if it's too far away to just skip to it.

Comment: If I could skip it in a nice way, that would be great. How would one implement that?

Comment: Also, if I run the code as-is at from this post, it will catch the error for the first entry, find the 'ID' for the next 2 ones, and then error again at the last one. Why the last one? That is a short DNA string.

`    Too big element...
    OU641503
    Y19466
    Too big element...`

Comment: The problem with `XmlReader` is that it doesn't recover well from errrors. You need to prevent it erroring in the first place. As I said, you could write a custom `Stream` that wraps the original, and checks how far away the next tag is, and if it's too far it just skips forwards.